# Reading off the Fourier coefficients whether a function is everywhere locally bounded except for finitely many points

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose we consider an $L^2$-function

$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.

How does the property "$f$ is a.e. bounded by a rational function" translate in terms of the Fourier coefficients?

I should say: I don't really care about whether there is a *rational* function all too specifically. I just want to ensure that my function is everywhere locally bounded except for finitely many points, and some growth control at these exceptional points - e.g. in the form of a rational function; but other types of growth estimates would also be welcome, e.g. anything like knowing a bound of the shape

$f \le \frac{1}{x-\frac{1}{2}}$ or $f \le -\log(x)$

would be great.

Comment: You don't say very specifically what type of condition on $\widehat{f}$ exactly you have in mind, but I'm skeptical. For example, there's the result that for any sequence $a_n\in\ell^2$ there's a *continuous* function $f$ with $|\widehat{f}_n|\ge |a_n|$. Roughly speaking, this says that the conditions on $f$ you impose give you precisely nothing on the rate of decay of $\widehat{f}$.